# Displaying an error message without reloading the page in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, user-experience

I have a page that lets one create records - if the validations aren't satisfied, it redirects to the same page and shows an error message. Here's that snip from the controller:

```
def create
  @signature = Signature.new(signature_params)
    if @signature.save
      redirect_to "/thanks"
    else
      redirect_to :back, :notice => error_messages(@signature)
    end
end
```

The trouble is, this is resulting in a full page refresh - so the error message isn't visible because the input form is placed under the fold of the page. I can place it at the top of the page, of course, but is there a way to show the message without reloading the page? Thanks.

Comment: Are you partial to using `ajax` or another asynchronous technology set?

Comment: Are you looking for client side validation. Please check out this episode http://railscasts.com/episodes/263-client-side-validations

Comment: Thanks for the link, but my plan is to add client-side validations after I've figured out a way to do a smoother server-side validation. If I'm not mistaken, validating on both sides is best practice.

Comment: @RichPeck: I'm not partial to using ajax, I just haven't found a clear guide on how to use it with flash messages.

Comment: You wouldn't use the flash - you'd handle the error through the `respond_to` block of your controller's action & display the error using Ajax. Small but significant difference!

Comment: @RichPeck Great, any references to a live code example that demonstrates this?

Comment: https://github.com/leonid-shevtsov/unobtrusive_flash can be very useful for displaying errors through ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so here's what I've settled on:

1) I'm handling validation on the client side with HTML5 "required" attributes - they were created for this explicit purpose and no other gems or plugins are needed. They are supported in all major browsers. [Details in this article.](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/html5-forms-pt2.html)

2) I've moved the error messages to the top of the page to handle the case in which a user either is on an old or mobile browser or has JavaScript disabled. Error messages must work with a complete request-response cycle (even if this means re-loading the page) before they work with anything else - this is the unobtrusive JavaScript approach.

3) For the AJAX version, I'm going to be using `remote: => true` on the form element [as explained in the Rails guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html). I might be making this open source once I'm done with the callback part of it, and will post a link here.

Comment: It would be absolutly nice if you post a demo o some code of how you end up solving this problem to understand better.

Answer (score -1):

Obviously, handling errors with flash is the most uniform & DRY way to show the user what's going on, but if you're willing to think outside the box, you'll be able to use Ajax to accomplish a similar job by just handling the errors yourself:

---

**Code Example**

```
#app/controllers/signatures_controller.rb
def create
  @signature = Signature.new(signature_params)
    if @signature.save
      @success = "true"
    end

    respond_to do |format|
        format.js   { @errors = error_messages(@signature) }
        format.html {
            if @success.defined?
                redirect_to "/thanks"
            else
                redirect_to :back, :notice => error_messages(@signature)
            end
        }
    end
end 

#app/views/signatures/create.js.erb
<% unless @success.defined? %>
    alert(<%=j @errors.inspect() %>)
<% end %>

#app/assets/javascripts/signatures.js
$(document).on("submit", "#signature_form", function() {
   $.ajax({
        url: "/signatures"
        type: "POST"
        data: $(this).parent().serialize(); //serialize the form (not the button)
        error: function() {
            alert("Sorry, there was an error!");
        }
   });
});
```

You'd actually be better using JSON for this. If you like the idea, I can refactor it to include JSON for you!

Comment: Looks promising, but the state handling with the @success variable in the controller doesn't work - the variable isn't accessible from inside the ´respond_to´ block. Also, I'm creating the signatures on the index / root view - but I've modified your code to reflect this. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Hope everything goes well & you should update us with your answer